# MySQL Order by Data in a different table

Tags: mysql

I'be been really struggling with how to **Order By** data in a different table. Nothing I have tried seems to work. I want to be able to Order By 'Rating' which is in table 'Image'. Many thanks for any help.

```
SELECT ImageID FROM ImageLinks WHERE TypeID = 1 AND LinkID = 10003 AND ImageID IN (SELECT ID FROM Image WHERE Family = 1) ORDER BY Image.Rating Desc LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT i.ID
FROM ImageLinks il
INNER JOIN Image i 
  ON il.ImageId = i.ID
WHERE 
  il.TypeID = 1 
  AND il.LinkID = 10003 
  AND i.Family = 1
ORDER BY i.Rating DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thank you both for showing me how to do this, really appreciated. Worked first attempt by following these examples

Comment: Don't mention it! And never use sub-selects in where.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your tables

```
SELECT il.ImageID 
FROM ImageLinks  il
JOIN Image i ON (il.ImageID i.id)
WHERE il.TypeID = 1 
AND i.Family = 1
AND il.LinkID = 10003 
ORDER BY i.Rating Desc 
LIMIT 100
```